# Regular expression to match email addresses

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a TextEdit in order to contains a truly email address. I have a regular expression to do that, but it validates more than one address, and I just want to validate only one address, no more.

Here you are the expression I have:

```
/^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$/
```

It validates something like this:

```
yulien.paz@cav.desoft.cu, wcampbell@cav.desoft.cu
```

I need take the second email address out of the TextEdit.

So, How can I do that??

Note: I am sorry about my English.

Comment: It's broken. It doesn't allow email addresses in, for example, the .mobi, .info or .museum TLDs. Nor does it allow email addresses containing a plus character or capital letters. Throw this out.

Comment: @Campbell: We have girls on stackoverflow as well :)

Comment: If you need to take the 2nd email address out of the TextEdit, can you not use split() and use the 1st result from the resulting array (starting at index 0 I guess ?

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: If I'd known I would have combed my hair.

Comment: Probably the most popular regex question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Here a great library of regular expressions

http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email

And tester of regexp.

This is a sample
http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=88

^([\w-.]+)@(([([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}])|(([\w-]+.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))$

Comment: No regex anywhere near that short can properly validate an e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find email address inside a paragraph, none of the the above works. Instead you need to look for word boundary, ex.

```
\b[_\S\d-]+@[_\S\d-]+\.[\S]{2,3}\b
```

And then use /g if needed.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/
```

Comment: This regex will not allow for email addresses that contain a + sign. According to RFC 2822 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822), the following non-alphanumeric characters are valid in an e-mail address: ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _

Comment: Hmm.. ok but it would be much more longer than the above.

Comment: Oh yes. Very much longer. http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html ...that's why you don't ‘validate’ e-mail addresses with regex.